# "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send" api doesn't work when sending the data object

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I use expo go and expo 48 on the frontend and firebase admin sdk on the backend. using cloud functions I push notifications like

[image: expo API sending notifications from the server]

When I send the body, everything works fine but when I try to send the data object nothing happens. I sometimes don't receive the notification at all or sometimes it comes and the data object is null. I use "expo-notifications": "0.18.1" like this

[image: expo handling incoming notifications]

Everything was working before just fine and there was no issue and then all of a sudden I had this issue. I'm having this issue going on for 5 days now. thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Here is the code for both images

```js
import axios from "axios";
export default async function sendPushNotification(expoPushToken, title, data) {
  try {
    const message = {
      to: expoPushToken,
      sound: "default",
      title: title,
      data: data,
    };
    await axios.post("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", message, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending notification:", error.message);
  }
}
```

and

```js
useEffect(() => {
  notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(async (notification) => {
    const body = notification.request.content.body;
    const data = notification.request.content.data;
    console.log(body);
    console.log(data);
  });
  return () => {
    Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: toyota supra sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems back to normal. since I'm using firenase emulators with "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", I might have hit the expo notifications free tier limit for the month and that the number of notifications I can send reset to 0